# Video tools which show hand drawing pictures?

Tags: animation

I was inquisitive, about a thing many youtubers do - storytelling with a hand drawing the pictures - if you know what I mean.

It's like the hand is drawing them real quick and the hand is like moving in a scribbly fashion.

Since many youtubers do it, it seems like it is automated - how is it done?

Answer (score 1):

It's usually just a [timelapse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-lapse_photography) video - you [lock-off a camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rostrum_camera) above your drawing on a white board or sheet, then make sure you have consistent soft lighting across the white sheet.  Expose the sheet to be near full white, then record the drawing.  Then speed it up to the required rate for your video.  Then edit it all together using Premiere if it's simple edits, or After Effects if there are any more complex animations or
thing you need to add in.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering; but I'm not sure that is the only possible way. Have a look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOLXv3nqDkI, do you think that hand is real? looks fake to me